# d3.js drawing a curve between set of points

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to make a floor plan. I am adding outer walls of a floor. Once of the wall (front wall) is not straight (it is arch shaped). It passes through 6 pillars.

So I have total 6 points (representing pillars) say (x1,y1) (x2,y2)  (x6,y6).

I want to draw a line starting from (x1,y1) passing through (x2,y2) (x5,y5) and ending at (x6,y6). I don't want a straight line but should be arch like line.

How can I do this in d3.js ? Pl. help.

Comment: In particular, you should have a look at the line generator in D3.